# Indeed API XML feed always returns only 25 results

Tags: php, xml, feed

I'm trying to use the Indeed.com XML Feed API's in a PHP website. I use this script https://github.com/indeedlabs/indeed-php, see how it works on the Github page (very good script, thanks to the author).

It works but Indeed always returns only 25 results for jobs, even when I set the 'limit', 'start' and 'end' parameters.

Here are the parameters I send :

```
$aParams = array(
         "q" => "php",
         "l" => "paris",
         "co" => "FR",
         "limit" => 10000,
         "sort" => "date",
         "start" => 0,
         "end" => 100,
         "userip" => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
         "useragent" => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
             "v" => 2,
             "format" => "json",
             "publisher" => "123456789"
   );
```

An array is returned and contains :

```
[version] = 2 
[query] = 'php'
[location] = 'paris'            
[dupefilter] = 'true'
[highlight] = 'true' 
[start] = 1 
[end] = 25  
[totalResults] = 2068  
[pageNumber] = 0 
[results] = an array which contains the jobs informations
```

As we can see, totalResults is equal to 2058 but real the jobs results array always contains only 25 entries.

It seems to be a pagination issue (read here : [http://forums.appthemes.com/report-jobroller-bugs/indeed-integration-api-37420](http://forums.appthemes.com/report-jobroller-bugs/indeed-integration-api-37420/)) but I don't understand the goal : why proceed like this and not more simply ? So I have to do many requests : one to know first the 'totalResults' and save it (in session for example) and other requests to paginate the results 25 by 25 until the last?

Are there any developers who use this API and how do you proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe its limited, because the Indeed.com limiting the results to 25 ...

Comment: OK @pes502, but in this case how to display all the results ? And it has no sense if Indeed want webmasters to use the API... Maybe they don't want many people use it because they have to pay the webmasters when ads/jobs are clicked?

Comment: You can bypass that limit when you run your script in loop. In this loop you will increase the start and the end value. [0] => (start:1, end:25), [1] => (start:25, end:50), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Right Indeed limits the feed to 25 at a time. I have written script to get round this. In the Indeed $params you can specify a 'start' which as default is 0.

I have created a script which using the job count creates a foreach loop and loops the API changing the 'start' to keep getting different results until theres no more left. Then it puts it all into a single PHP array.

Single API request just so we can get **totalResults** (count of total jobs)

```
$client = new Indeed("YOUR_ID");
$args_count = array(
    "q" => "YOUR SEARCH QUERY",
    "l" => "",
    "co" => "GB",
    "userip" => "1.2.3.4",
    "limit" => 10000,
    "useragent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)"
);
```

Once we have the total job count we divide it by 25 and round the result up. This is so we know how many times we need to run our foreach

```
$totalResults = $client->search($args_count);
$totalCount = $totalResults['totalResults'] / 25;
$loop_to_count = ceil($totalCount);
```

We create a array starting with 0 and going up in 25s to as many as you require. My below will return 150 results.

```
$counter = 0;
$loop_options = array('0', '25', '50', '75', '100', '125', '150');
```

Then we start the main foreach:

```
$results = '';

foreach ($loop_options as $options) {

    $params = array(
    "q" => "YOUR SEARCH QUERY",
    "l" => "",
    "co" => "GB",
    "userip" => "1.2.3.4",
    "limit" => 10000,
    "start"  => $options,
    "useragent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)"
    );
    $getResults = $client->search($params);

   foreach ($getResults['results'] as $rawResults) {

       $Subresults[] = array(
        'jobtitle' => $rawResults['jobtitle'],
        'company' => $rawResults['company'],
        'city' => $rawResults['city'],
        'state' => $rawResults['state'],
        'country' => $rawResults['country'],
        'language' => $rawResults['language'],
        'formattedLocation' => $rawResults['formattedLocation'],
        'source' => $rawResults['source'],
        'date' => $rawResults['date'],
        'snippet' => $rawResults['snippet'],
        'url' => $rawResults['url'],
        'onmousedown' => $rawResults['onmousedown'],
        'jobkey' => $rawResults['jobkey'],
        'sponsored' => $rawResults['sponsored'],
        'expired' => $rawResults['expired'],
        'indeedApply' => $rawResults['indeedApply'],
        'formattedLocationFull' => $rawResults['formattedLocationFull'],
        'formattedRelativeTime' => $rawResults['formattedRelativeTime'],
        'stations' => $rawResults['stations']
        );
   }
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == $loop_to_count) { break; }
}
```

Finally all our results are inside this array:

```
$results = array ('results' => $Subresults);
```

**$results will contains all the jobs you have posted on Indeed**

Answer (score -2):

please give limit attribute i gave 50 eg : 
http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=1772xxxxxxxxx&q=java&l=austin%2C%20tx&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=50&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2

Here you are using a library so you have to modify library function process_request() , in that function add a line $args["limit"] = 50; . here i just gave 50 you can initialize whatever number you want.

Comment: max limit suggested by the api document is 25.