# "Start" and "end" parameters with the Indeed API

Tags: javascript, http, express

I'm making a call to the Indeed API to get back a list of jobs. According to their [(limited) documentation](https://ads.indeed.com/jobroll/xmlfeed), it accepts `start` and `end` as parameters. When I try that, as here:

```
var api_request = 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=' 
                + config.API_KEY 
                + "&format=" + format 
                + "&limit=200"
                + "&start=10"
                + "&end=20"
                + "&userip=" + ip 
                + "&useragent=" + user_agent 
                + "&v=2" 
                + "&q=" + req.params.query
  request(api_request, function(err, response, body){
      if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
          res.json(body)
      }
  })
```

what happens is the `start` parameter remains at its default value (0), and the `end` value takes the `start` value I passed. I have absolutely no idea how or why that's happening. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble applying an end value as well... I'm wondering if it doesn't allow you to set it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098850/indeed-api-xml-feed-always-returns-only-25-results

Comment: Hey @A.com, I solved this by changing the order of the parameters, which seems weird, but works. I got rid of the `end` parameter, then put the `limit` parameter directly after the `start` parameter. Again this is weird and unfortunately I can't explain why it works, but it did for me. Hope it does for you too.

Comment: unfortunately this is just not working for me... http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=4745352910248302&q=company:forbes+OR+safeway%20title:sales&start=275&limit=1000&l=&radius=&sort=&v=2&psf=advsrch